# Passive and gerund

Tags: passive-voice

I've seen the following construction of a passive:

> *I can't stand being kept waiting.*

Can I always use ***being*** to construct a passive like the above example?

> *I won't allow being taken away.*

Does this work?

Comment: The passive gerund is fine, but it needs a subject; *allow* doesn't work like *stand* = *endure*

Comment: Ah, okay, like *I won't allow myself being taken away*?

Comment: Yes, that's grammatical. But it's a rare use with first person and future reference; an infinitival is more likely, and should be preferred: "I won't allow myself to be taken away."

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide an answer with more examples? I'm quite interested.

Comment: It's a complicated matter; I'll try to work something up when I can find the time, if somebody else doesn't pop in. In the meantime you might take a look at the Wikipedia article on [*Control*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_(linguistics)).

Comment: @StoneyB But we can write this - **Our simple algorithm allows finding a single nearest neighbor match across translations only...** Here **allow** takes **verb+ing** form. Considering this why can't we write the sentence with **allow** in the question?

Comment: A better example sentence - **" Through-the-telescope photography allows capturing closeups of Saturn."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I won't allow being taken away.

This sentence doesn't work for me, but I think the problem with it is semantic rather than syntactic; that is, the problem is that it doesn't make sense.

"I won't allow [gerund phrase]" means "I forbid people to [infinitive phrase]". But "to be taken away" is not something that people *choose* to do (since it's not really "doing" anything); so it doesn't make sense to "forbid" them from doing it.

This is the same reason that we rarely combine the passive voice with the imperative mood; it makes sense to say, "Go away!", but not to say, "Be taken away!"

---

Incidentally, note that, in this respect, "allow [gerund phrase]" is different from "allow [object] [infinitive phrase]"; something like

> I won't allow the students to be taken away.

is perfectly meaningful: it means that the speaker will prevent anyone from taking the students away.

Comment: After I'd seen my example again, I realised it makes no sense.